# automatically saved value in a UpdateView Django

Tags: django, methods, django-models, django-forms, django-views

i'm new in Django and i'm learning about the views and the methods and how they work, especially with this problem. The thing is that I would like to know how to automatically save a value of a field in my model after updating an object in a UpdateView, for example when I update an object, in this case a report where I can assign a person to do it, I would like to save a model value that shows the "status" and save the value of "assigned" or something like that, to know if the report was already assigned or not. I know there are methods and that maybe one of them could be done by overwriting the class, but I do not know how to apply it or which one to use.

For help this is a simple class of a UpdateViews that i'm using:

```
class reporteupdate(UpdateView):
model = reporte_fallo
form_class = ReporteAsignar
template_name = 'formulario/jefe_asignar.html'
success_url = reverse_lazy('formulario:reporte_listar_jefe')
```

and the field of the model that I would like to assign a value to is called **status**.

i'm waiting for your help, since I'm stuck with that doubt. Thanks!!!

Comment: You need to post your models too for better understanding

Answer (score 0):

the query dict will be changable after you create a copy of it in post method so you can do this:-

```
class SomeUpdateView(UpdateView):
    model=your model
    form_class=you form


    def post(self, request, **kwargs):
    request.POST = request.POST.copy()
    request.POST['status'] = 'Assigned'
    return super(SomeUpdateView, self).post(request, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could perhaps set the status flag after the form has been successfully validated, by overriding the [`form_valid()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/class-based-views/mixins-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.ModelFormMixin.form_valid) method in your `reporteupdate` view:

```
class reporteupdate(UpdateView):

    ...

    def form_valid(self, form):
        # Call super() to save the model and return the success url
        resp = super().form_valid(form)

        # Set your status flag
        self.object.status = 'assigned'  
        self.object.save()

        return resp
```